# Calling data from DataSet (Nested If)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, dataset, rdlc

Generate.aspx.vb

```
Case "costcentersummary"
            Dim newparams(4) As ReportParameter
            newparams(0) = New ReportParameter("CallClassCode", callClassCode)
            newparams(1) = New ReportParameter("DateTimeFrom", startDateTime)
            newparams(2) = New ReportParameter("DateTimeTo", endDateTime)
            newparams(3) = New ReportParameter("Vat", vat)
            newparams(4) = New ReportParameter("CostCenterBy", costcenterby)
            rvScreen.LocalReport.SetParameters(newparams)
            rvScreen.LocalReport.Refresh()

            Dim rdsCostCenterSummary As New ReportDataSource
            Dim daCostCenterSummary As New CostCenterSummaryTableAdapter
            Dim dtCostCenterSummary As New CostCenterSummaryDataTable

            Dim filters = reportFilter.Split(",")
            Dim ta As New LCSRDBDataSetTableAdapters.CostCentersLookupTableAdapter
            Dim dt = ta.GetData(siteId)

            If String.IsNullOrEmpty(reportFilter) Or filters.Count = dt.Rows.Count Then
                daCostCenterSummary.SetWhereClause(String.Format("cdr_site_id = '{0}' AND cdr_datetime BETWEEN '{1}' AND '{2}' AND cdr_call_class_code = 'OUTGOING' AND cdr_call_type_id IN({4}) GROUP BY cdr_id", siteId, startDateTime, endDateTime, callClass, callType))
            Else
                daCostCenterSummary.SetWhereClause(String.Format("cdr_site_id = '{0}' AND cdr_datetime BETWEEN '{1}' AND '{2}' AND cdr_call_class_code = 'OUTGOING' AND cdr_call_type_id IN({4}) AND cost_center_id IN ({5}) GROUP BY cdr_id", siteId, startDateTime, endDateTime, callClass, callType, reportFilter))
            End If

            daCostCenterSummary.Fill(dtCostCenterSummary)

            rdsCostCenterSummary.Name = "LCSRDBDataSet_CostCenterSummary"
            rdsCostCenterSummary.Value = dtCostCenterSummary
            rvScreen.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rdsCostCenterSummary)
```

Standard.aspx.vb (session)

```
 If (rbCostCenterName.Checked) Then
        Session("CostCenterBy") = "name"
    ElseIf (rbCostCenterNumber.Checked) Then
        Session("CostCenterBy") = "number"
 End If
```

Output
[image: Output in RDLC report]

Question:
How can I have nested if statement in the generate.aspx.vb?
Or should I code it in standard.aspx.vb?
How can I call value from the dataset?
Is it possible?
Or I should code it in rdlc report?

The idea is:

```
if(ByCostCenterName is checked) then
  CostCenterName is in alphabetical order
  if(ByCostCenterNumber is checked) then
    CostCenterNumber is in ascending order
  end if
end if
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay then, I got the answer.

In Generate.aspx.vb, I inserted the following code there.

```
If costcenterby = "name" Then
  daCostCenterSummary.SetWhereClause(String.Format("cdr_site_id = '{0}' AND cdr_datetime BETWEEN '{1}' AND '{2}' AND cdr_call_class_code = 'OUTGOING' AND cdr_call_type_id IN({4}) GROUP BY cdr_id ORDER BY department_description", siteId, startDateTime, endDateTime, callClass, callType))
Else
  daCostCenterSummary.SetWhereClause(String.Format("cdr_site_id = '{0}' AND cdr_datetime BETWEEN '{1}' AND '{2}' AND cdr_call_class_code = 'OUTGOING' AND cdr_call_type_id IN({4}) GROUP BY cdr_id ORDER BY cost_center_description", siteId, startDateTime, endDateTime, callClass, callType))
End If
```